# Advice to coordinate a long-term research project

Tags: research-process, projects

I have been granted a five-year project to conduct my own research. The project not only covers the salary but also offers a budget to hire personal assistance and purchase lab equipment. It is an exciting opportunity for me because I will acquire new skills in project management, mentoring, and supervision of PhD, master or undergraduate students. After defending my PhD thesis several years ago, I have been working as a postdoctoral researcher at four different institutions and I have reached a point in my career where I would like to take more responsibility in terms of supervising and coordination. I am currently working on previous scientific articles from my last postdoctoral positions, but I hope they will be published soon.

Overall, the new position is a dream job for any researcher, but I could not hide my worries about this new challenge since it is the first time that I have been awarded with such a long-term and ambitious project. I am obviously thrilled about this recognition but at the same time I am concerned about whether I will be able to achieve the objectives and deliver the results in each of the project’s working packages in the proposal.

For this reason, I would like to hear some of your thoughts or any recommendations to manage the fundings well, select the most qualified people, deal with administrative tasks, and overall promote a work-life balance in a research group.

Comment: Rinot, I'm afraid I flagged your post. I wavered between "needs more focus" and "opinion-based" but went with "needs more focus." At a minimum, the areas of concern should be divided up into different questions. Everyone has different styles of management, etc so the separate questions may still be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: And perhaps serendipitously, Ask a Manager has a [roundup post](https://www.askamanager.org/2023/01/advice-for-new-managers.html) today of past posts focusing on new managers.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it needs more focus, so I voted to close your post, but you can always upload a new (better) one.